# Running a groovy application under Maven

Tags: maven-2, memory-leaks, groovy

We have developed a Groovy application. Under development for starting it we use the following command line

```
 C:\myapp>mvn grails:run-app
```

Without sending any request to the server one can see how the memory used by the java process in increasing and increasing. When it starts at about 100M are allocated and a couple of hours later -without doind anything- the memory goes up to 300M.

When I start the application directly

```
C:\myapp> grails run-app
```

the memory consume is somehow different, without sending any request it is somehow stabilized at 110M. Sometimes goes up, sometimes comes down.

Although 300M is not critical I would like to know if this is a memory leak or not.

Is anybody having similar behaviours?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a memory leak in Maven, but more likely a leak in the grails:run-app command. I would suggest posting this on the Grails development mailing list.

Why does this concern you? You should only be using these commands for development, not production as you'd be deploying a war file in production. If you're simply concerned, the Grails development mailing list is definitely the place for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a memory leak here.

It's perfectly normal for the JVM to wait on doing a full GC until it has to.  That means if you allocate more memory, your java/groovy process will happily consume it.

Most likely you have different default memory settings for Maven vs Grails.  I'm not sure exactly how these properties are set in windows, but they look something like:

GRAILS_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx110m"

MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx300m"